# How can I copy effective codes frm bootstrap css

Tags: copy, twitter-bootstrap-3, barcode-scanner

I have used bootstrap 3 to my design. In bootstrap css file there are many codes. I do not use all.

Now, I want to keep codes only related to classes I have used.

How can I do it.

Comment: did you use `less` or pure css?

Answer (score 0):

You could customize your Bootstrap file and only select the componets you need:

[getbootstrap.com/customize/](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)